# How to solve for $x$ for $\frac{1}2 x^{-1/2}- \frac14x^{-3/4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This is a derivative and I am trying to find the max and min.  Right now I am trying to solve for x.

$$\frac{1}2 x^{-1/2}- \frac14x^{-3/4}$$

$$\frac{1}{2 x^{1/2}}- \frac1{4x^{3/4}}$$

$$\frac{1}{2 x^{1/2}}(\frac{2x^{\frac32}}{2x^{\frac32}})- \frac1{4x^{3/4}}$$

??

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s only an *equation* that may be solved for one of the variables. Without an equals sign, it’s not automatically clear what you’re asking for. In fact, I assumed that you had $y$ equaling the expression you wrote, and wanted to solve that for $x$ (in terms of $y$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as an equation by appending $=0$  Multiply by $x^{3/4}$, move one term to the other side, and raise both sides to a convenient power.

Answer (score 3):

If we have$$\frac{1}2 x^{-1/2}- \frac14x^{-3/4}=0$$
then we multiply both sides by $x^{3/4}$ to get 
$$\frac 12 x^{1/4}-\frac 14=0.$$
Solving for $x$ gives $x=\frac{1}{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you intended to post the following equation, 
\[
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{x^3}}=0
\]
Here's how you can solve for $x$,
\[
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\sqrt[4]{x^3}-\frac{1}{4\sqrt[4]{x^3}}\sqrt[4]{x^3}=0\cdot \sqrt[4]{x^3}
\]
\[
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[4]{x} -\frac{1}{4}=0
\]
\[
\sqrt[4]{x}=\frac{1}{2}
\]
\[
(\sqrt[4]{x})^4=\frac{1^4}{2^4}
\]
\[
x=\frac{1}{16}
\]
However as Lubin stated, your question is not as clear as it should be.